# Facebook Share callback not working

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to setup a Facebook page-tab app that contains a share button.  It works fine enough to present the share dialog, but the callback isn't being called.  If I put the FB.ui function inside the window.fbAsyncInit function, then the callback works great.  But, doing so makes the share window appear on page load.  I'd like to have it show on a button click.  I've tried calling the window.fbAsyncInit function only after the button is clicked, but that doesn't work either.  Here's the full HTML of my page:

```
   <html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body style="background-color:#9ec64e;">
       <div id="fb-root"></div>


          <table style="width:100%">
              <tr><td>
                  <br>
          <h1>Press button to share</h1>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p id="enterButton"><a href='' onclick="showShare();"><img src='share_btn.png' style='width:200px;'></a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

          <script>
        function showShare() {
            console.log("showShare");
           FB.ui(
             {
               method: 'feed',
               name: 'Facebook Dialogs', // name of the product or content you want to share
               link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/', // link back to the product or content you are sharing
               picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg', // path to an image you would like to share with this content
               caption: 'Reference Documentation', // caption
               description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.' // description of your product or content
             },
             function(response) {
                 console.log("finished");
               if (response && response.post_id) {
                 alert('Post was published.');
               } else {
                 alert('Post was not published.');
               }
             }
           );
        }
       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
           // init the FB JS SDK
            FB.init({
              appId      : 'XXXXXXXXX',
              xfbml      : true,
              version    : 'v2.2'
            });

           // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here


         };

            (function(d, s, id){
                     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

       </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I don’t see why this shouldn’t be working. Any errors in browser console? Can you show a live example of the page tab?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/Custom.Church/app_445281012302515

Comment: OK, you need to go read [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) first of all – asking people to share to enter a competition is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks - didn't realize that.  Seems like a lot of people do it these days, but I've taken it down now.  Still doesn't answer the question as to why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine in desktop and android but this is not working in iphone. Following function shares post in iphone but not showing Post was published ( I think response is not working in iphone 5 ). And change all parameters

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>    
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    status: true, 
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
});

function share_prompt() {
FB.ui( {
method: 'feed',
name: "fsdfsdf",
link: "abc.com/share-it/",
picture: "FacbookShareRed.jpg"

}, function( response ) {

if (response && response.post_id) {
          alert('Post was published.');
         } else {
           alert('Post was not published.');
         }


} );
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button.share-btn').on( 'click', fb_share );
});

</script>
<a class="sc-facebook" value="Share with Facebook" onclick="share_prompt();">Share with Facebook</a>
```